# Translating variable sometimes does not appear in the result after an ajax call

Tags: ajax, time, call

I was using the code bellow to retrieve via ajax a value from a database and then translate it with t object (dictionary).
**Sometimes it is translated other's nothing appears**.

In the beginning of the page i read a file dictionary to an objet (t). Could it be because of the time to read de file?

I am stuck :\ I would appreciate very much if someone could give an hint how to solve this mistery?

```
var json = JSON.parse( response );          // success function
var type_aux=t[json[0].type];
alert("->"+type_aux+"<-");
$('#TYPE_SHOW').html(type_aux);
```

Comment: debug the code and log the `t` and find out what value is has when you get nothing in translation.

Comment: It works in Firefox but not in chrome. In chrome only sometimes. It seems it depends on the page speed when loading

Comment: What is `response`? That is, what JSON are you parsing.

Comment: The value for t is undefined
The response is an object json[0].type, json[0].category,json[0].subcategory, etc.
Some of the variables are translated with the t diccionary.

Example:
https://www.mapadelisboa.com/qua/show.php?id_show=257&lang_show=pt
It works sometimes on chrome. On Firefox works all the time.